# MongoDb how to get all the objects in the document from client side

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express

I am trying to save the whole MongoDB object in the schema but I can only get the undefined value only

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

    MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
        if(err){
            console.log("no connect")
        }
       var dbo = db.db("mydb");
       var query = {name:"Company Inc"};
       dbo.collection("customers").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        db.close();
      });
    });
```

Actually it is throwing error

```
 W NETWORK [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused
```

I am connecting to the DB and I want to get the all the data from the MongoDB document

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add in some code ?

Comment: Sure @SasukeUchiha

Comment: did you tried `findOne` instead of `find`

Comment: Okay, I will try, Thanks @sohan

Comment: There is no mongoDb server listening on 127.0.0.1 on port 27017 or a firewall blocks that  connection. That is **not** something code can fix. You need to properly setup that server first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i'm getting following error while connecting to mongodb server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52873172/im-getting-following-error-while-connecting-to-mongodb-server)