# I cannot open mongo dB in my command prompt

Tags: mongodb

When I type the `"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongo.exe"` on my command promt to open mongo db, it says

```
    MongoDB shell version v4.4.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Comment: is mongod(mongodb server) actually running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting the MongoDB service by opening `services.msc`.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52874466/9217577) answer